# %%GLOBAL variables not working in custom Bigcommerce templates

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to customise the product template, but not for all cases hence I am creating a new template layout file.

I have tried to do this two ways, however both don't work and encounter the same issue with %%GLOBAL variables not working.

Using Product.html as a base, I created _Product.html and changed %%Panel.ProductDetails%% to my custom ProductDetails file %%Panel._ProductDetails%%, which I haven't customised at all at this stage. I then change a test product to use that template. When viewing the product, console errors ar produced and the page doesn't show properly. The cause of the first console error is a syntax error where script variables are being set to a %%GLOBAL variable. Looking at the page source, this is the result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var ThumbURLs = new Array();
var ProductImageDescriptions = new Array();
var CurrentProdThumbImage = ;
var ShowVariationThumb =false;
var ProductThumbWidth = ;
var ProductThumbHeight =  ;
var ProductMaxZoomWidth = ;
var ProductMaxZoomHeight =  ;
var ProductTinyWidth = ;
var ProductTinyHeight =  ;
```

where the template is

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var ThumbURLs = new Array();
var ProductImageDescriptions = new Array();
var CurrentProdThumbImage = %%GLOBAL_CurrentProdThumbImage%%;
var ShowVariationThumb =false;
var ProductThumbWidth = %%GLOBAL_ProductThumbWidth%%;
var ProductThumbHeight =  %%GLOBAL_ProductThumbHeight%%;
var ProductMaxZoomWidth = %%GLOBAL_ProductMaxZoomWidth%%;
var ProductMaxZoomHeight =  %%GLOBAL_ProductMaxZoomHeight%%;
var ProductTinyWidth = %%GLOBAL_ProductMaxTinyWidth%%;
var ProductTinyHeight =  %%GLOBAL_ProductMaxTinyHeight%%;
```

The weird part is that there are %%global variables just above it that work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_CdnAppPath%%/javascript/jquery/plugins/jCarousel/jCarousel.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
```

gets correctly gets interpreted as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-8a870c678fbffbf4184af752aed70da3f3454036/javascript/jquery/plugins/jCarousel/jCarousel.js?"></script>
```

The second way I tried was to include everything in the top level template. Instead of linking to %%Panel._ProductDetails%%, I inserted the contents of that panel into _Product.html, however this also encounters exactly the same issue.

Does anyone know why neither of these options work and how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because GLOBALS in the BigCommerce system will only print a value where they have been permitted by the BigCommerce development team. This can be a pain, especially for the values you are after, and what you want to do makes perfect sense.

At this time however, I suggest you make it known to the developers you want this at http://ideas.bigcommerce.com.

I can't say whether this will change anytime soon as the main reason for the GLOBALS being banned in certain areas is for security, although the ones you are after are useful, and I don't see why they aren't enabled either. Who knows, the developers may surprise us.

Comment: This answer explains the reason why. As a workaround I have multiple top level templates with different internal style sheets to change or hide things based on my needs.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call Panel.ProductDetails prior to using those variables.

Even if you are using a custom product details alternative panel you need to reference the standard one first. Then your global variables will work.

Comment: I just tried that and as I thought, it displays the panel then my panel so basically it displays the product info twice. I only want my panel to display.

Comment: You have to get creative and either hide the primary or move the content of the primary to another so that you are calling it first.